# Random variable question: Discrete uniform distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables

Can someone help me with this question? I'm trying to visualize this question but, I've studied the types of discret variables (Uniform Discret Probability, Bernoulli Distribuition, and Binomial Distribution) and I still don't get it how to do it.

Let X be a variable according to the Uniform Discret model probability, with values ​​in the set {1, 2, 3, ... , 10}.

a) What's the probability of X being less than 2 or grater than or equals to 8?

b) What's the probability of X being less or equals to 9, knowing that X is grater or equals to 6?

My first guess was to suppose each P(X) to be equals to 1/10, because there are 10 variables and none of them said that it must follow a rule. And then use the P(X≥2) = P(X=1)+P(X=2). But it still seems to be wrong.

Comment: Uniform means just that - each outcome is equally likely (cf. rolling a D10).

Comment: Yeah but even if I divide them to 1/10, to get the letter a) P(X≤2) or P(X≥8).
There will be:
P(X≤2) = P(X=1) + P(X=2) = 1/10 + 1/10 = 2/10
and 
P(X≥8) = P(X=8)+P(X=9)+P(X=10) = 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 3/10 
 what I'm supposed to do with the two sums?

Comment: "Less than" means "strictly less than." Check your work. If you can list the outcomes, it's easy to count.

Comment: Oh, true, it's P(X<2) or P(X≥8), then I've got P(X<2) = P(X=1) = 1/10, and also, P(X≥8)= P(X=8)+P(X=9)+P(X=10) = 1/10 + 1/10 + 1/10 = 3/10

Comment: I know should just add them ? P(X<2) + P(X≥8) ? to be 1/10 + 3/10?

Comment: Right... and so $\Pr(X<2~\text{or}~X\geq 8)=\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=8)+\Pr(X=9)+\Pr(X=10)$.  This follows from the general principle that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, that is if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, then $\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.

Comment: As for the next problem, this follows the definition of conditional probability... the punchline being that if we are told that we know that $X$ was necessarily greater than or equal to $6$, then it must have been that $X$ was one of the five possibilities $6,7,8,9,10$.  You can imagine this then as a uniform distribution over these five instead and continue as before.  Alternatively, you can approach directly by the definition, $\Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$